# Code runs fine in php 7 but returns error in php 8

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have the code bellow that runs fine in php 7. But when i change php to version 8 it gives me an error

The code

```
class WC_plugin {
        
    public static function init() {
        global $wp_filter;
        global $post;
        global $wpdb;
        add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', __CLASS__ . '::createXml' );
    }
    
    
    function createXml($product_id){
        // Do something
        

    }
    
}

WC_plugin::init();
```

And the error i am getting is the bellow one

```
Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, non-static method WC_plugin::createXml() cannot be called statically
```

Can anyone help with the above?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be clearly defined :

```
Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, non-static method WC_plugin::createXml() cannot be called statically
```

You can't call a method statically (with `::`) if this method is not static...

`createXml()` method is not a static method so you can't call it like this in your add_action : `WC_plugin::createXml();`

Maybe this should work better

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', [ $this ,'createXml' ] );
```

Which corresponds to the following call `WC_plugin->createXml();`

I hope this answer will be useful to you.

Comment: I give it a try, thanks!